# Kernel crashes when computing finite difference mixed derivative with respect to y & z but works fine when computing with respect to x & y or x & z?

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, bugs, numerics, finite-difference-method

**Bug introduced in 8.0.4 or earlier, fixed in 11.0.0.**

---

I am using Mathematica 10.4.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.

I am trying to solve a set of differential equations using finite difference method on an NxNxN cubic grid (x, y, z directions). I am getting a weird kernel crash when I am using `` NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative ``. My code is below. The code works fine when computing mixed derivatives with respect to x&y or x&z (`MXwx110` and `MXwx101`), but the kernel crashes every time I compute mixed derivatives with respect to y&z. I do not understand what is wrong. This is really weird.The whole thing was running perfectly fine before I had inserted boundary conditions (`BCwx1`) in the definition of the grid (`Wx1`) to make the code faster. I would really appreciate any help to resolve this issue. Thank you.

```
NN = 20; RMax = 20.0; delta = 1.0/NN;
xgrid = RMax*N[delta* Range[0, NN]];
ygrid = RMax*N[delta* Range[0, NN]]; zgrid = RMax*N[delta* Range[0, NN]];
fdd[l_, m_, n_] := NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[l, m, n], {xgrid, ygrid, zgrid},"DifferenceOrder" -> {4, 4, 4}];

BCwx1 = Flatten[{Table[{Subscript[wx1, 0, j, k] -> 0.0}, {j, 0, NN}, {k, 0, NN}],
Table[{Subscript[wx1, i, 0, k] -> 0.0}, {i, 0, NN}, {k, 0, NN}], 
Table[{Subscript[wx1, i, j, 0] -> 0.0}, {i, 0, NN}, {j, 0, NN}], 
Table[{Subscript[wx1, NN, j, k] -> 0.0}, {j, 0, NN}, {k, 0, NN}], 
Table[{Subscript[wx1, i, NN, k] -> 0.0}, {i, 0, NN}, {k, 0, NN}], 
Table[{Subscript[wx1, i, j, NN] -> 0.0}, {i, 0, NN}, {j, 0, NN}]},3];

Wx1 = Table[Subscript[wx1, i, j, k] /. BCwx1, {i, 0, NN}, {j, 0, NN}, {k, 0,NN}]; 

MXwx110 = D[Subscript[A, 1, 1][x, y, z], {x, 1}, {y, 1}, {z, 0}] -> fdd[1,1,0][Wx1] /. BCwx1;

MXwx011 = D[Subscript[A, 1, 1][x, y, z], {x, 0}, {y, 1}, {z, 1}] -> fdd[0,1,1][Wx1] /. BCwx1;

MXwx101 = D[Subscript[A, 1, 1][x, y, z], {x, 1}, {y, 0}, {z, 1}] -> fdd[1,0,1][Wx1] /. BCwx1;
```

Comment: Try not to use `Subscript`. It causes many problems...

Comment: Sure, I can try that. I have now localized the issue the definition MXwx011. I do not think the issue is really with the subscript....it would create problems my other two definitions otherwise as well. This is why I am finding it really weird !

Comment: Also, I copied the code from my mathematica notebook....Which is why you are seeing the subscript function explicitly.

Comment: `fdd[0,1,1][Wx1]` is causing the problem, and it is bizarre that all other possible combination of inputs (like `fdd[0,0,1][Wx1]`) work as intended...

Comment: Exactly. I narrowed down the error to fdd[0,1,1] as well. But I have no idea why this is happening even though my system is full symmetric (it is a cube).

Comment: Please in future state when cross-posting to Wolfram Community (preferably linking one to the other). Much easier for purposes of responding, bug tracking, etc.

Comment: Sure, Daniel. I didn't know that these two forums are connected which is why I posted on both forums. I will keep that in mind in future. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug that has been fixed as of Mathematica 11.0.0.

[image]